# Django mostrar una Lista en un Template

Tags: html, python, django, lista, template

estoy creando un programa que realiza un ping a un host, en una lista estoy almacenando los resultados del ping y quiero publicar el resultado en mi template pero no me muestra nada y no se que estoy haciendo mal, espero me puedan ayudar

el codigo es el siguiente

views.py

```
def ping(request):
    errors = []
    line = []
    if 'ip1' in request.GET:
        ip1=request.GET['ip1']

        if not ip1:
            if 'ip2' in request.GET:
                ip2=request.GET['ip2']
                if not ip2:
                    errors.append('Por favor introduce una IP.')
                    return render(request, 'ping.html', {'errors':errors})
                else:
                    tre=tracert(ip2)
                    res1= "%s Host Traces" % ip2
                    return render(request, 'ping.html', {'res1':res1})  
            else:
                return render(request, 'ping.html', {'errors':errors})  
        else:
                response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip1 + " > /dev/null 2>&1")
                if response == 0:
                    res= "%s Esta En Linea" % ip1
                    os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"ping -c 4 " +ip1+"; exec bash\"'")
                    pin=os.popen('ping -c 4 '+ip1,"r")
                    while True:
                        lines=pin.readline()
                        if not lines: 
                            break
                        line.append(lines)

                    return render(request, 'ping.html', {'res':res}, {'line':line}) 
                else:
                    res= "%s No Esta En Linea" % ip1
                    return render(request, 'ping.html', {'res':res})
    else:
        return render(request, 'ping.html', {'errors':errors})

def tracert(ip2):
    ip2t=ip2
    os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"traceroute " +ip2t+"; exec bash\"'")
```

en la lisa line almaceno los resultados cuando imprimo la lista me muestra que fue almacenados correctos y luego la retorno pero al momento de publicar en el Template no me muestra nada adjunto el Template

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    {% load static from staticfiles %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static "css/ping/css/style.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static "css/ping/css/style.css" %}" type="text/css" media="all">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="autor"  content="Mikey">
    <meta name="description" content="SYSTEM HACKING">
    <title>PING SYSTEM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{%  url 'ping' %}" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
        {% if errors %} 
            <ul> 
                {% for error in errors %} 
                <li style="color: red;">{{ error }}</li> 
                {% endfor %} 
            </ul> 
        {% endif %} 
        <h1><a target="_blank">HACKING SYSTEM PING</a></h1>

        <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1">
            <thead align="center">
                <tr align="center">
                    <th></th>
                    <th align="center"><p style="color:white;">PING</p></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th align="center"><p style="color:white;">TRACER ROUTE</p></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td align="center" style="color: white">IP HOST</td>
                    <td align="center"> <input type="text" name="ip1" align="center"> </td>
                    <td align="center">  <input type="submit" name="boton" value="PING" align="center">  </td>
                    <td align="center" style="color: white">IP HOST</td>
                    <td align="center"> <input type="text" name="ip2" align="center"> </td>
                    <td align="center">  <input type="submit" name="boton" value="TRACER" align="center">  </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody> 
        </table>

        <table align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th align="center" style="color: white"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        {% if line%}
                            {% for i in line %}
                                <TEXTAREA rows="5" cols="30" name="txtsugerencias">{{i}}</TEXTAREA><BR>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        {% if res %}
            <h2 align="center"><p style="color:white;">Resultados PING {{ res }} </p></h2> 
        {% endif %}

         {% if res1 %}
            <h2 align="center"><p style="color:white;">Tracert En Curso {{ res1 }}</p></h2> 
        {% endif %}

        <table align="center">

                <tr align="center">
                    <td>
                        <a href="/menu" style="color: white"> Exit </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>   

        </table>    


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi codigo HTML quiero mostrar los datos en un TEXTAREA pero no me muestra nada espero que me puedan ayudar ya que e intentado de muchas formas y no e logrado mostrar esta informacion

Resumen

Por si mi explicacion no fue clara, con `pin=os.popen('ping -c 4 '+ip1,"r")`, realizo un ping a un host que el usuario ingresa, realizo un ciclo para almacenar los resultados en una lista

```
while True:
    lines=pin.readline()
    if not lines: 
       break
    line.append(lines)
```

Ahora retorno la lista line al template `return render(request, 'ping.html', {'res':res}, {'line':line})`

Pero al momento de mostrar la lista line en el template no me muestra nada el codigo que estoy usando es

```
{% if line%}
                        {% for i in line %}
                            <TEXTAREA rows="5" cols="30" name="txtsugerencias">{{i}}</TEXTAREA><BR>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Estoy viendo que estás haciendo un while true, posiblemente eso esté ejecutandose en bucle y esté fallando.

Comment: Gracias ya revice eso y al revisar la lista si esta almacenando la informacion no se por que no se publica en el template

Comment: El código en HTML no debería agregar un textarea por cada línea. En su lugar debería crear el textarea y dentro de este el for agregando una línea y un salto (\n).

Comment: Hola a todos nada que se soluciona el tema sigo trabajano realice estos cambios. 1. en el template {% if context%}
                            {% for con in context %}
                                {{ con }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}   y no me muestra nada es nada

Comment: y en el views cree una funcion y ahora envio asi las variables a render, context={'line':line} return render(request, 'ping.html', {'res':res}, context), cree una funcion donde realizo el ping lo almaceno en mi lista al imprimirla sale todo pero al enviarla al template nada no se que pasa

Comment: Juan D. Gomez gracias por el consejo me podrias decir como lo puedo hacer que no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Hola todos quiero dar gracias por la ayuda logre corregir el error ya funciona la solucion fuen dos pasos el primero.

el codigo del views.py

```
def ping(request):
errors = []
line = []
if 'ip1' in request.GET:
    ip1=request.GET['ip1']

    if not ip1:
        if 'ip2' in request.GET:
            ip2=request.GET['ip2']
            if not ip2:
                errors.append('Por favor introduce una IP.')
                return render(request, 'ping.html', {'errors':errors})
            else:
                tre=tracert(ip2)
                res1= "%s Host Traces" % ip2
                return render(request, 'ping.html', {'res1':res1})  
        else:
            return render(request, 'ping.html', {'errors':errors})  
    else:
            response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip1 + " > /dev/null 2>&1")
            if response == 0:
                res= "%s Esta En Linea" % ip1
                line=pingaux(ip1)
                os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"ping -c 4 " +ip1+"; exec bash\"'")
                #context={'line':line}
                return render(request, 'ping.html',{'line':line}, {'res':res})  
            else:
                res= "%s No Esta En Linea" % ip1
                return render(request, 'ping.html', {'res':res})
else:
    return render(request, 'ping.html', {'errors':errors})


def tracert(ip2):
ip2t=ip2
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"traceroute " +ip2t+"; exec bash\"'")

def pingaux(ip1):
line1=[]
ip1t=ip1
pin=os.popen('ping -c 4 '+ip1t,"r")
while True:
    lines=pin.readline()
    if not lines:break
    line1.append(lines)
return line1
```

bueno cambie el codigo y cree una funcion para almacenar en la lista el ping y retorno el valor

en el codigo html

```
 {% if line %}
                            <textarea rows="12" cols="51" style="color: red; background-color: black" >{{ line }}</textarea>
                            <h2 align="center"><p style="color: white"></p></h2>
                    {% endif %}
```

de esta manera se muestra todo el arreglo dentro de la textarea y asi publica todo el arreglo

y por ultimo aunque suene loco o raro reinicie mi servidor donde trabajo y desarrollo mis aplicaciones que tiene debian 9 y reinicio el servidor django y asi funciono, y luego de pruebas el reinicio del servidor fue la verdadera solucion